# Knights Tour -- Something I am doing wrong

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity, backtracking

I have an assignment to write a knights tour backtracking program in Java where the professor says to:

Eliminate backtracking time by:

```
Find the knights with the least possible moves
Sort those moves from knight with least moves to greatest moves
Backtrack if that path fails
```

I have done that with and attempted some other optimizations but my algorithm is still pretty slow for most squares. I went online and found my algorithm was pretty similar to others. I even took the algorithm from [here](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-knights-tour-problem/) and found it ran slow on the same spaces as mine (*ahem* pretty much never finishes) I was ready to call it until I took my processor's version from his website and it ran instantaneously on the squares *every other version I had seen had run slowly on*, he even showed me his code in his office last week and I recall it looking very similar. I have also seen questions on this site asking about their slow backtracking programs for knights tour. How is this possible!? Virtually every other source I have seen can confirm that this algorithm is slow except for my professor. My code:

```
    /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
//Grid.java THIS IS WHERE THE MEAT AND POATATOS IS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
public class Grid
{
    //Constants to keep things consistant and avoid errors.//
    public final static char OBSTICLE_TILE_SYMBOLE = '0';
    public final static char OPEN_TILE_SYMBOLE = '1';
    private Tile[][] tileGrid;
    /*************************************************
    ** 'Makes for a nice api to do things this way, **
    ** no construtor discourages the user from *******
    ** making a standalone "Grid" object or **********
    ** or setting it up manually (though they have ***
    ** the choice to), and encourages them to ********
    ** do things the easy magical way. ***************
    *************************************************/
    public static Grid CreateGridFromFile( String fileToLoadMapFrom )
    {
        try
        {
            Grid newGrid = new Grid();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileToLoadMapFrom ) );
            String line = "";
            boolean tileGridSetUp = false;
            int y = 0;
            //Standard reading procedure.//
            while( ( line = buffer.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                line = line.trim().replaceAll( "\\s+", "" ).replaceAll( "\n", "" ).replaceAll( "\r", "" );
                final int LINE_LENGTH = line.length();
                if( tileGridSetUp == false ) {
                    newGrid.SetTileGrid( new Tile[ LINE_LENGTH ][ LINE_LENGTH ] );
                    tileGridSetUp = true;
                }
                //Construct nodes in graph.//
                for( int x = 0; x < LINE_LENGTH; ++x ) {
                    newGrid.SubstituteTile( x, y, new Tile( new XY( x, y ), 
                            Tile.DEFAULT_ACCOUNTED_FOR_STATE_FLAG, line.charAt( x ) ) );
                }
                ++y;
            }
            return newGrid;
        }
        catch( Exception exception )
        {
            System.out.println( "Exception::Grid::CreateGridFromFile()::General exception, " + 
                    "\n\tprinting information and stack trace. @Exception::!Cause: " + exception.getCause() + 
                    ",!Message" + exception.getMessage() + "$ Stack Trace: \n" );
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return ( null );
        }
    }
    public void GridToSystemOut()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < tileGrid.length; ++i )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < tileGrid[ i ].length; ++j )
                System.out.print( tileGrid[ i ][ j ].GetTileSymbole() );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public void ConditionallyAddToArray( ArrayList< Tile > toAddTo, ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE coordinateFilter, Tile toAdd )
    {
        if( toAdd != null )
        {
            if( ( ( coordinateFilter == ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.OCCUPIED && toAdd.GetTileSymbole() == Grid.OBSTICLE_TILE_SYMBOLE ) == true ) || 
                    ( ( coordinateFilter == ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.OPEN && toAdd.GetTileSymbole() == Grid.OPEN_TILE_SYMBOLE ) == true ) || 
                    coordinateFilter == ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.ALL )
                toAddTo.add( toAdd );
        }
    }
    public Tile ReturnIfInRange( int x, int y )
    {
        if( y > 0 && y < tileGrid.length ) {
            if( x > 0  && x < tileGrid[ 0 ].length )
                return tileGrid[ y ][ x ];
        }
        return ( null );
    }
    public ArrayList< Tile > AdjecentCoordiantes( Grid toReadFrom, Tile adjecentTo, ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE coordinateFilter, boolean excludeAdjecentTo )
    {
        final int AMOUNT_OF_LINES = toReadFrom.GetTileGrid().length;
        if( adjecentTo.AttainY() < AMOUNT_OF_LINES )
        {
            ArrayList< Tile > adjecentCoordinates = new ArrayList< Tile >();
            final int X = adjecentTo.AttainX();
            final int Y = adjecentTo.AttainY();
            if( excludeAdjecentTo == false )
                ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, adjecentTo );
            //Yay for hardcoding!//
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X + 1, Y - 2 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X + 2, Y - 1 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X + 2, Y + 1 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X + 1, Y + 2 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X - 1, Y + 2 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X - 2, Y + 1 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X - 2, Y - 1 ) );
            ConditionallyAddToArray( adjecentCoordinates, coordinateFilter, ReturnIfInRange( X - 1, Y - 2 ) );
            return adjecentCoordinates;
        }
        return ( null );
    }
    //Uses of the method above because it has so many options.//
    public ArrayList< Tile > AllAdjecentCoordiantes( Grid toReadFrom, Tile adjecentTo, boolean excludeAdjecentTo ) {
        return AdjecentCoordiantes( toReadFrom, adjecentTo, ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.ALL, excludeAdjecentTo );
    }
    public ArrayList< Tile > OpenAdjecentCoordiantes( Grid toReadFrom, Tile adjecentTo, boolean excludeAdjecentTo ) {
        return AdjecentCoordiantes( toReadFrom, adjecentTo, ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.OPEN, excludeAdjecentTo );
    }
    public ArrayList< Tile > OccupiedAdjecentCoordiantes( Grid toReadFrom, Tile adjecentTo, boolean excludeAdjecentTo ) {
        return AdjecentCoordiantes( toReadFrom, adjecentTo, ADJECENT_COORDINATE_TYPE.OCCUPIED, excludeAdjecentTo );
    }
    //See if a node in the list is 'accounted for.'//
    public ArrayList< Tile > AttainAccountedFor( ArrayList< Tile > listOfTiles, boolean accountedForState )
    {
        ArrayList< Tile > accountedFor = new ArrayList< Tile >();
        for( Tile currentTile : listOfTiles ) {
            if( currentTile.GetAccountedFor() == accountedForState )
                accountedFor.add( currentTile );
        }
        return accountedFor;
    }
    //See if an object is in the list.//
    public static < ELEMENT_TYPE_T > boolean IsInThisList( ArrayList< ELEMENT_TYPE_T > listToTest, ELEMENT_TYPE_T instanceToTest )
    {
        for( ELEMENT_TYPE_T currentNode : listToTest ) {
            if( currentNode == instanceToTest )
                return ( false );
        }
        return ( true );
    }
    public boolean HopToTile( Tile firstNode ) {
        return HopToTile( this, 0, firstNode );//, goUntil, ( goUntil + 1 ) ) == false )
    }
    public boolean HopToTile( Grid toReadFrom, int order, Tile currentNode )//, int last, int goUntil )
    {
        if( order >= ( ( tileGrid.length * tileGrid[ 0 ].length ) - 1 ) )
            return ( true );
        currentNode.SetOrder( order );
        currentNode.SetAccountedFor( true );
        ArrayList< Tile > hopTiles = AttainAccountedFor( OpenAdjecentCoordiantes( toReadFrom, currentNode, true ), false );
ArrayList< Tile > tilesToTry = new ArrayList< Tile >();
        ArrayList< Integer > tilesToTryLengths = new ArrayList< Integer >();
        for( Tile currentHopTile : hopTiles )
        { 
            ArrayList< Tile > currentNodeTiles = AttainAccountedFor( OpenAdjecentCoordiantes( toReadFrom, currentHopTile, true ), false );
            final int CURRENT_LENGTH = currentNodeTiles.size();
            if( CURRENT_LENGTH > 0 )
            {
                final int AMOUNT_OF_TILES_TO_TRY = tilesToTry.size();
                boolean foundAPlace = false;
                for( int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_OF_TILES_TO_TRY; ++i )
                {
                    if( CURRENT_LENGTH < tilesToTryLengths.get( i ).intValue() )
                    {
                        if( i > 0 )
                        {
                            tilesToTry.add( ( i - 1 ), currentHopTile );
                            tilesToTryLengths.add( ( i - 1 ), Integer.valueOf( CURRENT_LENGTH ) );
                            foundAPlace = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if( foundAPlace == false ) {
                    tilesToTryLengths.add( Integer.valueOf( CURRENT_LENGTH ) );
                    tilesToTry.add( currentHopTile );
                }
            }
        }
        for( Tile currentHopTile : tilesToTry )//hopTiles )
        {
            if( HopToTile( toReadFrom, ( order + 1 ), currentHopTile ) == true )
                return ( true );
        }
        currentNode.SetOrder( Tile.DEFAULT_ORDER );
        currentNode.SetAccountedFor( Tile.DEFAULT_ACCOUNTED_FOR_STATE_FLAG );
        return ( false );
    }
    /**********************************************************************
    ** * : "Substitute" indicates a convience encuasulated method *********
    **      similar to set (or affectivly set) of something conceptual ****
    **      not reflected in the code or possibly actual ******************
    **      reflected in the code. ****************************************
    ** * : "Modify" indicates a convience encuasulated method similar to **
    **      set (or affectivly set) of something but it is not just *******
    **      a set, it may involve other things, possibly a ****************
    **      "safe set," or a systematic way of setting something. *********
    ** * : "Attain" is similar to both "Modify" and "Substitute," *********
    **      for get, Attain can mean a convience encuasulated method ******
    **      similar to get (or affectivly get) of something conceptal *****
    **      not reflected in the code, or something possibly **************
    **      actual reflected in the code, or it can mean ******************
    **      something similar to get (or affectily get) but may not *******
    **      be a straight get, it could be something like a "safe" ********
    **      or systematic get, the thing being "Attained" can also ********
    **      be generated within the method, non - existant, and or ********
    **      static data, for example a constant string containing *********
    **      the name of a class put in as meta data. **********************
    **********************************************************************/
    public void SetTileGrid( Tile[][] tileGrid_ ) {
        tileGrid = tileGrid_;
    }
    public void SubstituteTile( int x, int y, Tile toSubstitute )
    {
        if( y < tileGrid.length && y >= 0 ) {
            if( x < tileGrid[ 0 ].length )
                tileGrid[ y ][ x ] = toSubstitute;
        }
    }
    public void SetTileRow( int y, Tile[] rowToSubstitute ) {
        if( y < tileGrid.length )
            tileGrid[ y ] = rowToSubstitute;
    }
    public Tile AttainTile( int x, int y )
    {
        if( y < tileGrid.length && y >= 0 ) {
            if( x < tileGrid[ 0 ].length )
                return tileGrid[ y ][ x ];
        }
        return ( null );
    }
    public Tile[] AttainTileRow( int y )
    {
        if( y < tileGrid.length )
            return tileGrid[ y ];
        return ( null );
    }
    public Tile[][] GetTileGrid() {
        return tileGrid;
    }
}

//Tile.java
public class Tile
{
    private XY coordinate;
    private boolean accountedFor;
    private int order;
    private char tileSymbole;
    //Constants to keep things orginised and grounded.//
    public static final boolean DEFAULT_ACCOUNTED_FOR_STATE_FLAG = false;
    public static final char DEFAULT_TILE_SYMBOLE = Grid.OBSTICLE_TILE_SYMBOLE;
    public static final int DEFAULT_ORDER = ( -1 );
    public static final XY DEFAULT_COORDINATES = new XY( ( -1 ), ( -1 ) );
    public Tile() {
        this( DEFAULT_COORDINATES );
    }
    public Tile( XY coordinate_ ) {
        this( coordinate_, DEFAULT_ACCOUNTED_FOR_STATE_FLAG );
    }
    public Tile( XY coordinate_, boolean accountedFor_ ) {
        this( coordinate_, accountedFor_, DEFAULT_TILE_SYMBOLE );
    }
    public Tile( XY coordinate_, boolean accountedFor_, char tileSymbole_ ) {
        this( coordinate_, accountedFor_, tileSymbole_, DEFAULT_ORDER );
    }
    public Tile( XY coordinate_, boolean accountedFor_, char tileSymbole_, int order_ )
    {
        coordinate = coordinate_;
        accountedFor = accountedFor_;
        tileSymbole = tileSymbole_;
        order = order_;
    }
    public void SubstituteX( int x ) {
        coordinate.SetX( x );
    }
    public void SubstituteY( int y ) {
        coordinate.SetY( y );
    }
    public void SetCoordinate( XY coordinate_ ) {
        coordinate = coordinate_;
    }
    public void SetAccountedFor( boolean accountedFor_ ) {
        accountedFor = accountedFor_;
    }
    public void SetTileSymbole( char tileSymbole_ ) {
        tileSymbole = tileSymbole_;
    }
    public void SetOrder( int order_ ) {
        order = order_;
    }
    public int AttainX() {
        return coordinate.GetX();
    }
    public int AttainY() {
        return coordinate.GetY();
    }
    public XY GetCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }
    public boolean GetAccountedFor() {
        return accountedFor;
    }
    public char GetTileSymbole() {
        return tileSymbole;
    }
    public int GetOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Broken sort

When inserting elements into your list in sorted order, you don't insert the element at the correct index:

> ```
>        for( int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_OF_TILES_TO_TRY; ++i )
>         {
>             if( CURRENT_LENGTH < tilesToTryLengths.get( i ).intValue() )
>             {
>                 if( i > 0 )
>                 {
>                     tilesToTry.add( ( i - 1 ), currentHopTile );
>                     tilesToTryLengths.add( ( i - 1 ), Integer.valueOf( CURRENT_LENGTH ) );
>                     foundAPlace = true;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

Suppose you had 10 elements already sorted and your new element were larger than index 4 but smaller than index 5.  Your new element should be inserted at index 5 and shift all the other elements down.  In your code, however, you are inserting at index 4, which is incorrect.  You also have a check for `i > 0` which is wrong.  Your code should be changed to this:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_OF_TILES_TO_TRY; ++i)
           {
                if (CURRENT_LENGTH < tilesToTryLengths.get(i).intValue())
                {
                    tilesToTry.add(i, currentHopTile);
                    tilesToTryLengths.add(i, Integer.valueOf(CURRENT_LENGTH));
                    foundAPlace = true;
                    break;
                }
           }
```